# Replace with incrementing number

Tags: python

I have a simple task from school. I have to replace all values of `int-count` to `int-count + i`
Here's an example of original data. There's a huge amount of similar lines.

```
"first-int": 0,
"first-int-id": 0,
"int-count": 1

"first-int": 64,
"first-int-id": 0,
"int-count": 2

"first-int": 78,
"first-int-id": 1,
"int-count": 3

"first-int": 1,
"first-int-id": 1,
"int-count": 4

"first-int": 655,
"first-int-id": 0,
"int-count": 5
```

I found an example of code on Python. It works perfectly with an author's example.
I changed it for me but it works wrong.
First of all I decided to check results on exact numbers. Here's my code

```
import re
import fileinput
with fileinput.input(files="file.xml", inplace=True, backup='.original.bak', mode='r') as f:
            for line in f:
                result = re.sub('"int-count": (\d+)', lambda exp: "{}".format(int(exp.group(1)) + 1), line)
                print(result, end='')
```

It replaces whole string to `old number +1`
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of the lambda replaces everything that's matched. So you need to include the `"int-count":` part.

```
result = re.sub('"int-count": (\d+)', lambda exp: '"int-count": {}'.format(int(exp.group(1)) + 1), line)
```

Comment: Could you tell me is it possible to add multiple output files instead of one? I mean a While operation. For example while n < 5 do that script but set output file as new one.

Comment: `fileinput` just writes back to the same file you're reading. You could have another loop around this that processes multiple files. Or you could use normal file operations to write a different file than you're reading.